# Selecting items from s series of lists using Python

Tags: python, list, pandas, series

I want to be able to select certain parts of a Series of lists using python

I currently have a dataset that looks like this

```
0    [s, d, g]
1    [f, g, d]
2       [d, s]
dtype: object
```

and I want to be able to select a subset of this for each row. In my particular case I would like to be able to select the first two entries. So to create a series that looks like

```
0    [s, d]
1    [f, g]
2    [d, s]
dtype: object
```

I have tried

```
for i in Series:
    i = Series[:1]
```

and things like

```
Series = Series[[:1]]
```

but clearly I dont really know what I am doing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
s = pd.Series(['s d g','f g d','d s']).str.split()
print (s)
0    [s, d, g]
1    [f, g, d]
2       [d, s]
dtype: object

s1 = s.str[:2]
print (s1)
0    [s, d]
1    [f, g]
2    [d, s]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thats amazing. Thank you @jezrael